# Raise Warning when Table and Column Names are Equal in Snowflake Join

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Occasionally users submit a query where the table and column names are equal in the join condition. This can lead to fan-outs.

*Example*

```
select
    table_a.*
from table_a
left outer join table_b
    on table_a.col_1 = table_a.col_1
```

Exception handling seems to be only available for [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions).

Is there a programatic way to raise a warning when this happens?

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by "fan outs"? If you are asking whether it is possible to raise a warning when someone is just writing/running SQL statements through the UI then the answer is no. You can stop run away queries by setting appropriate timeout parameter values, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Provided query is still a **syntactically valid query**:

```
select
    table_a.*
from table_a
left outer join table_b
    on table_a.col_1 = table_a.col_1;
```

Effectively equivalent of (assuming that `col_1` is not nullable):

```
select
    table_a.*
from table_a
left outer join table_b
    on true;
```

or just `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select
    table_a.*
from table_a
cross join table_b;
```

Snowflake and any other RDBMS cannot predict if such construct is intended or not.

---

From performance standpoint such behavior is called [“Exploding” Joins](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile#exploding-joins)

> One of the common mistakes SQL users make is joining tables without providing a join condition (resulting in a “Cartesian product”), or providing a condition where records from one table match multiple records from another table. **For such queries, the Join operator produces significantly (often by orders of magnitude) more tuples than it consumes.**
>
> **This can be observed by looking at the number of records produced by a Join operator, and typically is also reflected in Join operator consuming a lot of time**